# how to debug inconsistency between yum list on different machines

Tags: yum, rhel5

I have two different RHEL5.8 machines, which have exactly the same /etc/yum.repos.d/ and /etc/yum/. On one machine when I do `yum search openssl-devel` or `yum search yum-utils` I get a result, on the other I do not. I installed the repository that I have as follows:

```
rpm -Uhv http://redhat-clientconfig-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el5.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-10.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
```

I also cannot find any result for `yum search httpd` to install apache.

So, how can I resolve the yum inconsistency? And how do I install the latest httpd (say even without enabling RHN)?

Comment: Running rhn_register seems to be an easy fix. But wonder if there's a way around doing an RHN registration.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly discovered that the systems need to be registered with an RHN server for the yum searched to work. Otherwise, yum has no server or repository to search.